# Job Ad - A Legitimate Business needs discreet help. What do they need?

Tags: riddle

Need a courier to help us send a message. **Must have good aim.**

Are you something of a creative type, the type whose mind moves in ways other than black and white? Do you understand discretion when collaborating in a group? Can you listen to a very, very specific story and share that story with others?

Join The Business Corporation, a **completely legitimate operation** specializing in making dreams into reality for those whose got the money, not specializing in crime.

Scrawled in the margins:

> Still trying to shoot with a 35 mm cartridge? Why not just do away with wasting metal? Hit 'em with a digital photoelectromagnetizer to get the job done. Our employees get the newest "tools" that offer pinpoint accuracy from far away and are completely electronic. The evidence left behind of your highly successful business dealings is in your hands and nobody else's.

You're told what to do and you get the job done. The last thing your target's going to see before the big sleep is what you have done. No games.

With a multi-talented crew beside you, we're sure your work is going to be a real hit with everyone; they'll all be left seeing stars and you'll be seeing a whole lotta moolah.

If you're ready to climb the redberry tree to the top and be the best, contact Gaumont.

**What are you being asked to do and how long is the prison sentence if there is one? Be certain and provide your reasoning; you'll end up needlessly unemployed or behind bars if you don't.**

Comment: Attention all riddlers! [Vote](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/are-puzzles-and-riddles-welcome/1681#1681)! :-)

Comment: @Len Sorry, I've been busy with work. I marked the other as correct because of the explanation. Expand yours and you'll get the win.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are asked to

> Be a cameraman, no prison sentence.

Explanation:

Need a courier to help us send a message. Must have good aim.

> The message is the movie, and good aim is required with a camera.

Are you something of a creative type, the type whose mind moves in ways other than black and white? Do you understand discretion when collaborating in a group? Can you listen to a very, very specific story and share that story with others?

> Movie making is a creative endeavour, movies are not made in black and white anymore, discretion is required so as to not leak the film's script to the outside world, and the story you are sharing is the story of the movie.

Join The Business Corporation, a completely legitimate operation specializing in making dreams into reality for those whose got the money, not specializing in crime.

> Movies can turn dreams (things impossible in reality) into reality, but cost a lot of money.  They are also completely legitimate.

The margins:

> Scrawled in the margins is a message telling you to use digital video recorders instead of film.

You're told what to do and you get the job done

> The director tells you where to place the camera, when to shoot and when to cut.

The last thing your target's going to see before the big sleep is what you have done. No games.

> The movie watchers are going to see the film before going to bed.

With a multi-talented crew beside you, we're sure your work is going to be a real hit with everyone; they'll all be left seeing stars and you'll be seeing a whole lotta moolah.

> Film making requires a large crew; stars refers to movie stars and movies can make a lot of money as well.

If you're ready to climb the redberry tree to the top and be the best, contact Gaumont.

> Redberry refers to Hollywood.  Hollies have red berries.

Comment: Looks like Len beat me to it by 7 minutes.

Comment: But your explanation is much better =)

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you are being asked to be a:

> **cinematographer or a movie camera person** (and there is no prison sentence)

because:

> "other than black and white" suggests color
>  "discretion when collaborating" suggests not revealing the story
>  "very, very specific story" suggests the script
>  "dreams into reality" suggests bringing a story to life
>  "35 mm cartridge ..." suggests using digital video instead of chemical film
>  "seeing stars" suggests movie stars
>  Gaumont is a French film company